# How to send list value in jsp to controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm having the following class when i return the value jsp to contoller updateuser method the value of commonMonth show null value in the monthlyMemberSatus list. I don't know what is the mistake in my code... help me

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tempOpen",method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView monthMemberList(@ModelAttribute("commanMonth") CommanMonth commanMonth) {
    commanMonth.setMonthlyMemberStatus(dataService.listMonthMember());
    return new ModelAndView("hlo","commanMonth",commanMonth);
}

@RequestMapping("/tempClose")
public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("commanMonth") CommanMonth commanMonth) {
    System.out.println(month.getMonthlyMemberStatus());

    dataService.updateRow(month);
    return new ModelAndView("hlo","commanMonth",month);
}
```

MODEL class:

```
public class CommanMonth {
private List<MonthlyMemberStatus> monthlyMemberStatus;
public List<MonthlyMemberStatus> getMonthlyMemberStatus() {
    return monthlyMemberStatus;
}

public void setMonthlyMemberStatus(List<MonthlyMemberStatus> monthlyMemberStatus) {
    this.monthlyMemberStatus = monthlyMemberStatus;
}
```

Jsp Page: hlo.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
${commanMonth}
<form:form modelAttribute="commanMonth" method="post"
        action="tempClose.html">
        <table width="400px" height="150px">
            <c:forEach items="${commanMonth.monthlyMemberStatus}" var="list" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="monthlyMemberStatus[${status.index}].roomMembers.memberName" >${list.roomMembers.memberName}</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="monthlyMemberStatus[${status.index}].noOffDays" value="31"/></td>
                    <%-- <td style="visibility:hidden"><form:input path="li[${status.index}].bookId" value="${list.bookId}" readonly="true"/></td>
                        <td><form:input path="temp[${status.index}].book" value="hloloo"/></td>
                    </tr> --%>
                    </c:forEach> 
                    <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Update" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                </table>
    </form:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You dont specified @ModelAttribute("month") in your any getter method , so you need to defined that first to know spring controller with model attribute  has name 'month'

also try to add input tag like below instead of path

```
<td><input name="monthlyMemberStatus[${status.index}].noOffDays" value="31"/></td>
```

note: Also specify **RequestMethod.POST** in controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tempOpen",method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView monthMemberList(@ModelAttribute("commanMonth") CommanMonth commanMonth) {
    commanMonth.setMonthlyMemberStatus(dataService.listMonthMember());
    return new ModelAndView("hlo","commanMonth",commanMonth);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/tempClose", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("commanMonth") CommanMonth commanMonth) {
    System.out.println(month.getMonthlyMemberStatus());

    dataService.updateRow(month);
    return new ModelAndView("hlo","commanMonth",month);
}
```

Comment: i was changed   public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("commanMonth") CommanMonth commanMonth)  but still list value is null

Comment: Can you just check your network call , what data is passing when you submit the form ,if you are using chrome than press f12 > network tab>request header

Comment: I attached answer filed what data in  f12 > network tab>request header

Answer (score 0):

Request Headers
view source

```
   POST /sdnext/tempClose.html HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:8080
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 135
   Cache-Control: max-age=0
   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8080/sdnext/tempOpen.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B9D81D17E3B18B75494CBF8517B15995
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
monthlyMemberStatus0.noOffDays:24
monthlyMemberStatus1.noOffDays:31
monthlyMemberStatus2.noOffDays:31
monthlyMemberStatus3.noOffDays:31
```

Comment: Your method is by default GET so you need to specified RequestMethod.POST in controller method..look at my answer.( you can add comment in answer rather than posting another answer tab)

Comment: Even I tried with get method, it is also not working. Please get me a solution, waiting eagerly for your reply...

Comment: Here is reference , have a look in this   http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/

Comment: The project shared in the above link works fine for me, but when I try to copy that code and paste it in my existing code the same issue exists..(getting null value)

Comment: Than please copy your code here with servlet.xml and all

Comment: Also try to change input tag like my answers

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't update it in comments field,so posting it in Answer field. Here goes my Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.room" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.room.model.RoomMembers</value>
            <value>com.room.model.DailyExpense</value>
            <value>com.room.model.MonthlyExpense</value>
            <value>com.room.model.FinalSettlement</value>
            <value>com.room.model.MemberInOut</value>
            <value>com.room.model.SpecialExpense</value>
            <value>com.room.model.MonthlyMemberStatus</value>


        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```